# Streaming a file from S3 to the local filesystem in a Vue application

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-js

I have an open S3 bucket with encrypted files. I am trying to stream these files to the user's filesystem via a Vue application. Does anyone have sample code of how to do something similar?